# Devxpress grid currency formatting

Tags: wpf, datagrid, grid

I'm using Devxpress v13.1 and not allowed to upgrade it.

I am trying to render a devxpress grid from a dataset. I want $400.0000 to display as $400.00 and can't get it to work.

I have  the following code:

```
public MainWindow{
 DataSet TransactionList = GetDataFromXML();// Loads XML to DS
            TransactionGrid.ItemsSource = TransactionList.Tables[0];
            TransactionGrid.CustomColumnDisplayText += TransactionGrid_CustomColumnDisplayText; 

        }
void TransactionGrid_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender, DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)

        {
            if (e.Column.FieldName == "Amount1")
            {
                //e.Column.DisplayTemplate =
               e.DisplayText = String.Format("{0:0.00}", e.Value);

            }
        }
```

xaml code:

```
    <dxg:GridControl Name="TransactionGrid"        HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="Auto" Width="Auto" >
                <dxg:GridControl.View >
                    <dxg:TableView AllowEditing="False"></dxg:TableView>
                </dxg:GridControl.View>
                <dxg:GridControl.Columns>
                    <dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Amount1" Header="Amount1" Width="80" >                  
                    </dxg:GridColumn>
           </dxg:GridControl.Columns>
            </dxg:GridControl

>
```

Comment: Have you tried with StringFormat="c2"?

Comment: Yes and It doesnt work. Only way I can get it to work is to fire an event in the code behind. I would prefer to do this in the XAML

Answer (score 0):

I used the TGrid_CustomColumnDisplayText event to achieve the results. Trying to implement StringFormat="c2" didnt work at the xaml level. I had to  Call the statement below in the constructor of the xaml page.

```
TGrid.CustomColumnDisplayText += TGrid_CustomColumnDisplayText;
```

Event is as below-
    void Tgrid_CustomColumnDisplayText(object sender,
    DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.CustomColumnDisplayTextEventArgs e)
     {
              CultureInfo ciUsa = new CultureInfo("en-US");
                if (e.Column.FieldName == "Amount")
                {
                    e.DisplayText = String.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Value.ToString()) ? String.Empty : String.Format(ciUsa, "{0:c2}", Convert.ToDecimal(e.Value));
                }

```
        }
```